# can we pass a variable to data attribute of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, attributes

So far I know that we can store data in html element by using:

```
<div  data-test="hello">
$.("div").data("test")
```

However , I just can store raw text for data attribute

what I need is:

```
var t= hello
<div data-test=t>
```

but when I tried this , it shows the letter `t` instead of `hello`.

Comment: You should read up on the difference between HTML and the DOM, particularly the difference between HTML attributes and DOM node properties.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you are changing not the `attribute` but an property of the `DOM` object. For `data` JavaScript has it's own mechanism to hold `data` for the elements. For more take a look on [**Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

You can change the `data` using `jQuery` (as you have already used it). Use `data` function and pass your variable as the second argument to the function like `$("#d").data("test", t);`

```js
console.log($("#d").data("test"));

const t = 'hello';
$("#d").data("test", t); // <- second parameter

console.log($("#d").data("test"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d" data-test="test">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `attr()` function of JQuery instead of `data()`

```js
var t= 'hello';
$("div").attr("data-test",t);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div  data-test=t>asd
```

Answer (score 1):

## Without jQuery

jQuery is definitely unnecessary in this case. You can achieve the same thing with this code

#### HTML

```
<div data-test="hello">
```

#### JS

```
const textToChange = 'other text';
const divWithDataAttribute = document.querySelector('[data-test]');
diveWithDataAttribute.dataSet.test = textToChange;
```

## Conclusion

This will apply the new result to the data attribute and we didn't need jQuery.

A thing to note is the part `dataSet.test` this part comes from the `data-test` attribute. We drop the `data-` part and camel case the rest of the words.

For example `data-test-new-test="whatever"` becomes `testNewTest` when accessing the dataSet.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can try this:

```
 $("div").attr("data-test", "test");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var t="hello";
$("div").attr("data-test",t);
```